# How to setup nginx on devilbox to use nginx global variable mapping with php-fpm

Tags: docker, magento, nginx, configuration, magento-1.9

I want to setup devilbox to run my local Magento multistore setup.

- I use nginx as webserver
- I need different Subdomains (no problem with devilbox and nginx.yml file in project)
- I need different PHP Version (no problem with devilbox)
- I need a nginx-global variabe mapping like

```
    map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
      ### Local
      kkrieger.develop first_code;
      subdomainA.kkrieger.develop second_code;
      subdomainA.kkrieger.develop third_code;
      ### Default
      ~* default;
    }
    map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_TYPE {
      ~* store;
    }
```

to use these variables in my vhost config for php:

```
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $mage_run_code;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE $mage_run_type;
```

I tried to achieve this via nginx.yml file in my project but this is only [template for vhosts](https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vhost-gen/virtual-host-templates.html#nginx-template)

After that I created an additional .conf file in PATH_TO_DEVILBOX/cfg/nginx-stable/mapping.conf with content in it. But it seems that this does'nt work, too.

My current state:
- myproject.conf will not be generated
- devilbox says, that there's no valid DNS record for this domain in /etc/hosts - but it is.

How could I solve this?